# Vbscript RegEx expression meaning

Tags: regex, vbscript, expression, semantics

I'm new to using RegEx and I'm not sure what `objRegEx.Pattern = """([^""]+)"""` does I'm using a reference script which uses this on the text

```
Profiles on interface Wireless Network Connection:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
    <None>

User profiles
-------------
    All User Profile     : x
```

where **x** is the name of a wifi network; using MsgBox it gives **"Wireless Network Connection"** and x both in quotes

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
https://regex101.com/
```

To get an excellent explanation on your expressions. Here you can test them, too:

```
()     capture everything in a Group that occures
+      between one an unlimited times and contains of
[^"]   anything but "
```

The enslosing quotes are a formating condition. Usually the content of the capturing Group is later read by referencing it (e.g. by $1 or \1) - like it is done in your example with the MsgBox: Here the regex was used to parse the Input, get the value of the Wifi-String stored in a Group an then echo it.